# How can I fit a multiple linear regression model in R if the value for beta coefficient of each predictor is given?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression

I've got an exercise question asking me to fit a multiple linear regression model in R when the values of coefficients are given. I don't know how to do it.

specifically, I have 5 predictors in my question. and how can I fit such a multiple linear regression model in R if the beta coefficient of each predictor is given (e.g. beta1=2, beta2=-10, beta3=3, beta4=0 beta5=5)? Also, how to find the estimated intercept term with the known coefficients? I mean, is it even positive to do such thing in R?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the only thing left to *fit* is the intercept, correct?

Comment: hi, yes that's correct Mr. Stephan.

Comment: I am quite confused as it's like a "reverse" process relative to what we normally do when fitting a model.

Comment: Try writing out the regression equation, $y=X\beta+\epsilon$. We always know $y$ and $X$, and in this case, we also know part of $\beta$. Can you rearrange the equation to turn it into a different regression which is of the form above?

Comment: do you mean: y =intercept + 2*X_1 -10*X_2 + 3*X_3 + 0*X_4+ 1*X_5 + error. but how can i use this in R?

Comment: Very good. Can you solve for the unknown and the error?

Comment: i don't know how to do it in R.... is there any function i could use?

Comment: Solve the equation on paper to understand what you need to feed into R.

Comment: hi, i think i found intercept, but i don't know if i was doing it in the right way, this is the R code i used: mean(Y) -
(2*mean(X.1)+10*mean(X.2)-3*mean(X.3)-0*mean(X.4)-1*mean(X.5)). 
Intercept=47.81 (I also stored the intercept matrix, but don't know if it's useful or not)

Comment: i don't know how to calculate error since i don't have a fitted model yet. but do i need to calculate that? I remember the expected value of error in model with parameters equals to 0. so can i just write the model as below?: mortality=47.81+beta1*X1+...+beta5*X5+ε_i, where ε_i,~iid.N (0,σ^2).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Since you are asked to fit the regression, this probably means that you only need to fit the intercept parameter. Which you have done. Good job!